# how to interpret this MNIST tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, mnist

I have found a code that converts the data from the MNIST dataset into tensors. The code is the following:

```
import torch
import torchvision
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

batch_size_test=1000

test_loader=torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    torchvision.datasets.MNIST('/files/',train=False,download=True,
                               transform=torchvision.transforms.Compose(
                                   [torchvision.transforms.ToTensor(),
                                    torchvision.transforms.Normalize(
                                        (0.1307,),(0.3081,))
                                       ])),
    batch_size=batch_size_test,shuffle=True
    )

examples=enumerate(test_loader)
print (example_data.shape)
```

when I print the shape of the example_data I get the following:

```
torch.Size([1000, 1, 28, 28])
```

so, for what I know is a tensor of 1000 samples, 1 channel and images of 28 pixels of height and 28 pixels of width. Graphically, I imagine like a sort of a 4d array in which I have cubes, 1000 stacked one over another, each of then formed by 28 x 28 x 1 data.

I have also tried the following instruction:

```
print (example_data[2][0])
```

but the output is something like:

```
tensor([[-0.4242, -0.4242, -0.4242, -0.4242, -0.4242, -0.4242, -0.4242, -0.4242,
         -0.4242, -0.4242, -0.4242, -0.4242, -0.4242, -0.4242, -0.4242, -0.4242,
         -0.4242, -0.4242, -0.4242, -0.4242, -0.4242, -0.4242, -0.4242, -0.4242,
         -0.4242, -0.4242, -0.4242, -0.4242],
        [-0.4242, -0.4242, -0.4242, -0.4242, -0.4242, -0.4242, -0.4242, -0.4242,
         -0.4242, -0.4242, -0.4242, -0.4242, -0.4242, -0.4242, -0.4242, -0.4242,
         -0.4242, -0.4242, -0.4242, -0.4242, -0.4242, -0.4242, -0.4242, -0.4242,
         -0.4242, -0.4242, -0.4242, -0.4242],
```

I see that each part between brackets, like a sort of an unidimensional array, contains 28 numbers in an horizontal way, but why I have also 28 of this [] vertically?

Also, in this part: `print (example_data[2][0])`, the 2 refers to the second sample, but why I have to put the [0]?

Sorry, if it seems like two questions in one post, but I believe they are closely related to each other.

Comment: `why I have to put the [0]?` You're accessing the first channel. You said it yourself. `so, for what I know is a tensor of 1000 samples, 1 channel and images of 28 pixels of height and 28 pixels of width`

Answer (score 1):

As you said, MNIST is a `1000, 1, 28, 28` tensor. So each image is a `28x28` matrix. Obviously, it comprises 28 vectors of length 28 (first question)

For your second question, although MNIST has a single channel, generally, images could have three or even more channels in the torch. So you have to put the [0] as it is a dummy dimension for MNIST and makes the tensor a general form for all image types.